# How can i import a lib from node module in laravel

Tags: laravel, node-modules

Hello i want to load axios in a script tag with laravel
Something like that

```
 <script src="{{url('node_modules/axios/dist/axios.js')}}"></script>
```

but it's not working, i get this error

/node_modules/axios/dist/axios.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

do you have a solution, or it is nor possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible since the client doesn't have access to files outside your public directory. You should use some kind of asset compiler eg. [laravel mix](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix) or just use cdn like [cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/).

Comment: OK I will search more with laravel mix, also you can copy the code from the Lib online and put it in the public file, I was just searching for a way to use directly the node module scripts to I'm sad that it's not possible